# Postgres - Jsonb data querying and populating in view

Tags: postgresql-9.5

We have a data in one of the column called data

```
[ro{{key1:value1,key2:value1},{key1:value1,key2:value1}}]
{rol{key1:value1,key2:value1}}
```

As I stated above, when we have multiple set of records t is in square bracket, but when it has only single set of records it comes with out square bracket.

If I use `jsonb_array` extract, getting only records in square bracket

Can someone help me how to query this data?

I need all records in view like this:

```
value1  value1
value1  value1
value1  value1
```